# C# converting an array returned as a generic object to a different underlying type

Tags: c#, arrays, object, dynamic, type-conversion

I have a C# method which uses `object` as a generic container to return a data array which could be declared using different data types. Below a simplified example of such a method:

```
void GetChannelData(string name, out object data)
{
    // Depending on "name", the underlying type of  
    // "data" can be different: int[], byte[], float[]...
    // Below I simply return int[] for the sake of example
    int[] intArray = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    data = intArray;
}
```

I need to convert all the returned array elements to `double` but so far I could not find a way. Ideally I would like to perform something like:

```
object objArray;
GetChannelData("test", out objArray);
double[] doubleArray = Array.ConvertAll<objArray.GetType().GetElementType(), double>(objArray, item => (double)item);
```

Which miserably fails because `ConvertAll` does not accept types defined at runtime. I have also tried intermediate conversions to a `dynamic` variable, to no avail.

Is there any way to perform such type conversion in a simple manner?

Comment: All the provided answers are working fine; accepted the @AlexWiese version as correct answer as he provided such solution before AnyName. Thanks to all of you guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't know the type at compile time you can try to convert it.

```
var array = (IEnumerable)objArray;
var doubles = array.OfType<object>().Select(a => Convert.ToDouble(a)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't know the type of array elements at compile-time:

```
var doubleArray = (objArray as Array).OfType<object>()
    .Select(m => Convert.ToDouble(m)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the library method returns an `object` and not an `object[]`, so `Select` does not apply.

Comment: @Nkosi I didn't notice that. I've just updated my answer.

Comment: @AnyName, nice way but you actually convert to `int` at compile time, while I am just able to read the underlying type at runtime with a `GetType()`. Maybe my example is not 100% clear, I will try to edit it so that it is clearer

Answer (score 1):

u can create extension method..

```
        public static IEnumerable<T> Convert<T>(this IEnumerable source)
        {
           foreach (var item in source)
               yield return (T)System.Convert.ChangeType(item, typeof(T));
        }
```

using ..

```
        object objArray;
        GetChannelData("test", out objArray);
        var array = (IEnumerable)objArray;
        var doubleArray = array.Convert<double>().ToArray();
```